# data.table: recode several variables without having to specify the "by"

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table that looks like:

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)

foo_data <- data.table(
  x = rep("A", 6),
  y = sample(1:3, 6, replace = T),
  var1 = sample(c(1, 2),  6, replace = T),
  var2 = sample(c(1, 2),  6, replace = T)
)

> foo_data
   x y var1 var2
1: A 3    1    2
2: A 3    2    1
3: A 1    2    2
4: A 1    1    2
5: A 1    2    1
6: A 1    1    1
```

I want to recode `var1` and `var2`. I can do this with the following code but it only keeps those two variables:

```
foo_data[, lapply(.SD, function(x) fcase(x == 2, 0, x == 1, 1)),
         .SDcols = c("var1", "var2")]

   var1 var2
1:    1    0
2:    0    1
3:    0    0
4:    1    0
5:    0    1
6:    1    1
```

I can keep `x` and `y` by putting them in the `by` argument, but this becomes tedious if I have many variables that I want to keep.

```
foo_data[, lapply(.SD, function(x) fcase(x == 2, 0, x == 1, 1)),
         by = .(x, y)
         .SDcols = c("var1", "var2")]
```

How can I recode these two variables and keep the two others without putting them in `by`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can assign the output of `lapply` to the column names.

```
library(data.table)

cols <- c("var1", "var2")
foo_data[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) fcase(x == 2, 0, x == 1, 1)),.SDcols = cols]
foo_data

#   x y var1 var2
#1: A 3    0    0
#2: A 3    0    1
#3: A 3    1    0
#4: A 2    1    1
#5: A 3    0    0
#6: A 2    0    1
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `fifelse`

```
library(data.table)
cols <- c("var1", "var2")
foo_data[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) fifelse(x == 2, 0, fifelse(x == 1, 1))), .SDcols = cols]
```